# DynamoDB Querying using Global Secondary Index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to query all the rows which are created the last one week. I have created an index for `created` key in `AWS console`. In my query, I added the Key Condition with `ComparisonOperator.GT` for the `created` key. But When I run the query it throws an error like `Query key condition not supported`. If I give the condition as `ComparisonOperator.EQ`, it will return a single row. But not working for the `ComparisonOperator.GT`.

Code :

```
Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition();
    rangeKeyCondition.withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.GT).withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS("11:26 23/10/2018 "));

    Map<String, Condition> keyConditions = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
    keyConditions.put("created", rangeKeyCondition);


    QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest();
    queryRequest.withTableName(getTableName(TABLE_NAME));
    queryRequest.withIndexName("created-index");
    queryRequest.withKeyConditions(keyConditions);

    QueryResult result = EventStoreInitializer.getAmazonDynamoDBClient().query(queryRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read your case so for your desired output you should not create 'created' as Index bz it becomes key for the table and in keyCondition you can't use GT and LT operator.

you need to use FilterExpression and there you can use GT and LT for the 'created' field.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. If I use FilterExpression, then I would have to give the partition key as `ComparisonOperator.EQ` right?

Comment: Yes that will be in keycondition Expression and 'created' field condition is in filter expression.

Comment: What should I do if I want to query without keycondition?

Comment: It is mandatory field you have to provide key condition for partition key and filter expression for created field.